# Custom grok filter for logstash

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a log file as below which I need to parse using grok filter. Please guide me on what will be the filter

**log**

```
id:twsoper  AIX230 
JOB:load_data /jobs/system/load_data.bat 2017-05-14
trying to connect to database
connected to database Target_DB
```

**Expected Filter**

```
ID: twsoper
server : AIX230
Date : 2017-05-14
database : Target_DB
```

Comment: can you provide what you've tried so far; you're more likely to get help here if you do.

Answer (score 1):

When working with grok you need to know regex (for pattern matching).

Also, you need to play around with the pattern before you put it into logstash, for that here are some online pattern testers

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match.

Now on to your example. Assuming all of these are individual lines within the file, you are going to end up with a document in elastic search for all of these. Unless you look into multiline in filebeat or logstash to merge multiple lines into one single message.

```
filter {
    grok {
        # get the entire message 
        match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
        overwrite => [ "message" ] 
        # get ID and server
        match => ["message", "id:%{WORD:ID}\s+%{WORD:server}"]
        # get Date
        match => ["message", "JOB.+%{DATE:Date}"]
        #get database
        match => ["message", "connected to database %{WORD:database}"]
    }
}
```

if you do not want to use multiline, you will need if statements to match messages and then match fields, like so:

```
filter {
    #if line starts with id 
    if [message] =~ /^id/ {
        grok {
            # get ID and server
            match => ["message", "id:%{WORD:ID}\s+%{WORD:server}"]
    }
    #if line starts with JOB
    if [message] =~ /^JOB/ {
        grok {
            # get Date
            match => ["message", "JOB.+%{DATE:Date}"]
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```